# Resolving a local variable to be the value of the referenced local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, reference

I have a local variable that is the name of another local variable. I want to change the value of the first local variable to the value of the another local variable. Without hard coding, what is the best way to do this. In addition, I only have read access to the database. (Preferably I don't want to have write anything into the database)

example:

```
DECLARE @x1 VARCHAR(10), @x2 VARCHAR(10), @x3 VARCHAR(10), @x4 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @y VARCHAR(10)

SET @var1 = 'abc'
SET @var2 = 'def'
SET @var3 = 'ghi'
SET @var4 = 'jkl'
```

I want to change the value of @y to 'abc' if @y is initially equals to '@var1', 'def' if initial value is '@var2' and so on

Does anyone know how to do this without hard coding in the value since i can potentially have many more local variables?

I know one way to do this is the work with a system table that contains with all variable. Is there something like that for SQL, if yes what is the name of that table and how do i read from it.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: you can still define a local table variable, it is allowed on read only database too

Comment: I agree with @peterm - try telling us about the problem you are trying to solve rather than the problem with your proposed solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

All SQL injection warnings aside...

Using sp_executesql, you are able to get the value of a variable returned as a output variable.
Since @y has the name of the variable, all you need to do is build up the SQL statement that will assign the value to @y

```
DECLARE @var1   VARCHAR(10), 
        @var2   VARCHAR(10), 
        @var3   VARCHAR(10), 
        @var4   VARCHAR(10),
        @y      VARCHAR(10) = '@var1'

SET @var1 = 'abc'
SET @var2 = 'def'
SET @var3 = 'ghi'
SET @var4 = 'jkl'

DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 'SET @y = ' + @y;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'
    @var1   VARCHAR(10), 
    @var2   VARCHAR(10), 
    @var3   VARCHAR(10), 
    @var4   VARCHAR(10),
    @y      VARCHAR(10) OUT', 
    @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @y OUT

SELECT @Y
```